# Extending content to full width in CSS Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am new to Bootstrap and trying to customize an existing example of Bootstrap. My goal here is to extend the div tag (with id "inner") to full width of the screen.

I tried a lot of different ways but it didn't seem to work, including resetting the margin and padding on the horizontal. I also tried to use flex-box on the div tag with id "outer" and it didn't work. For all of the previous methods, for some reason the "inner" div tag is not in the center any more.

The last method I used was creating a new div.container-fluid tag which was inside the "outer" tag  and covered the whole "inner" div tag. However, it didn't work as well.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container my-5" id="outer">
    <div class="p-5 text-center bg-body-tertiary rounded-3" id="inner">
      <svg class="bi mt-4 mb-3" style="color: var(--bs-indigo);" width="100" height="100"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      <h1 class="text-body-emphasis">Jumbotron with icon</h1>
      <p class="col-lg-8 mx-auto fs-5 text-muted">
        This is a custom jumbotron featuring an SVG image at the top, some longer text that wraps early thanks to a responsive <code>.col-*</code> class, and a customized call to action.
      </p>
      <div class="d-inline-flex gap-2 mb-5">
        <button class="d-inline-flex align-items-center btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 rounded-pill" type="button">
                    Call to action
                    <svg class="bi ms-2" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#arrow-right-short"></use></svg>
                  </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg px-4 rounded-pill" type="button">
                    Secondary link
                  </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome! I would start by removing the `my-5` class on the `outer` div and `p-5` class on the `inner` div. `my-5` is adding margin on the y-axis, and the `p-5` is adding padding on all sides.

Comment: Read about containers https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/ Are you asking about `container-fluid` from that?

Comment: @isinfor
Thanks for your specific clarification. It turns out that the problem is about the outer div. I just need to set it to full width with container.fuild and delete the padding. padding for the inner div is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make both containers `container-fluid` and put padding (`p-0`) and margins (`m-0`) to 0 size.

You can decide if you still wish to have `p-5` on the inner container;

I put ugly borders on to show what is where only.

```css
#outer{border: solid #00ff00 1px;}
#inner{border: solid #ff0000 1px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid my-5 p-0" id="outer">
    <div class="p-5 container-fluid text-center m-0 bg-body-tertiary rounded-3" id="inner">
      <svg class="bi mt-4 mb-3" style="color: var(--bs-indigo);" width="100" height="100"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      <h1 class="text-body-emphasis">Jumbotron with icon</h1>
      <p class="col-lg-8 mx-auto fs-5 text-muted">
        This is a custom jumbotron featuring an SVG image at the top, some longer text that wraps early thanks to a responsive <code>.col-*</code> class, and a customized call to action.
      </p>
      <div class="d-inline-flex gap-2 mb-5">
        <button class="d-inline-flex align-items-center btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 rounded-pill" type="button">
                    Call to action
                    <svg class="bi ms-2" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#arrow-right-short"></use></svg>
                  </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg px-4 rounded-pill" type="button">
                    Secondary link
                  </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh okay I got it. Appreciate your help. The problem was a little bit simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a css file with these lines below in it with "min-width: 100% !important! to "overwright" bootstrap css for #outer and #inner divs

```css
#outer{
    min-width: 100% !important;
    /* padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important; */
}

#inner{
    min-width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: That is not really the "bootstrap" way

Comment: Yeah your solution worked as well. Thanks for your help. How did you figure out it was the min-width property? So if we set the width to 100vw and it still doesn't work, there should be some problem with max-width or min-width right?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you are right actualy

Comment: @tanLe if you check in the devtool Element style you can see that .container does have max-width